# How can I use .combinations() to replace multiple characters in a string?

Tags: python

first question I've asked on here. So I've learned how to generate and count all possible combinations from a range using this code I've come up with:

```py
import random
from random import shuffle
import itertools
import math
from math import factorial

# to calculate total number of combinations from a select range of elements:
# max!/(select_num_of_elems! * (max - select_num_of_elems)!

ranger = range(0,30+1) 

enlist_range=list(ranger)
print(f"well this what happens when you print the enlist_range...cuz its an array " + 
                                                                   "{enlist_range}")
max_val_of_range = len(enlist_range)
print(f"the length of enlist_range is {max_val_of_range}")

select_num_of_elems= int( input(f"enter in the range of select elements that will " + 
                                 "recombinate \n by the way it can't be more than the " +
                                 "range max of {max_val_of_range} \n") )


# max!/(select_num_of_elems! * (max - select_num_of_elems)!
total_combos = factorial(max_val_of_range)/( factorial(select_num_of_elems) * 
                                factorial( max_val_of_range - select_num_of_elems ) )
print()
print(f"the total number of combos from a range of {max_val_of_range} with "  + 
                                  "{select_num_of_elems} selected number of " +
                                  "elements is {total_combos}")
print()
for suby in itertools.combinations(enlist_range,select_num_of_elems):    
  print(suby)
```

How would I use the all combination values generated to simultaneously replace multiple characters in a string?

Say if I had a string:
`some_string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` 
For example, given a combination pair of [(0, 12)] I would like to get an output of:

```
_BCDEFGHIJKL_NOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Using `len(some_string)` This would make my `n value` 26 and say I chose an `r value` of 2 for this combination

I would generate combinations such as `[(0, 12)]` or `[(2,14)]` etc etc etc

I would like to get every Combination to replace a letter with a `'_'` I have tried breaking the string apart using `list(some_string)` and then using `for` loops in conjunction with `list(some_string).insert((combo_index), "_")` and then `[i+1] = ""` to erase a character. Then using `''.join(list(some_string))` to merge the new string together

But doing this generates a disappointing output of:

```
A____________BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
some_string = "ABCDE" #"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
n = len(some_string)
r = 2
for combination in itertools.combinations(range(n), r):
  print(''.join('_' if index in combination else char 
                for index, char in enumerate(some_string)))
```

Comment: Hey sorry for late post back but what is "char" supposed to be in the code?

Comment: `for index, char in enumerate(some_string)` iterates through `some_string`, and for every item (character) `index` is the index of that character and `char` is the character itself. For more details see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Interesting, I thought char data type was in Java but not Python. Ok this is actually super helpful, I will need to review char, index, and enumerate functions. Also I had no idea you could put loops and  if statements inside of print statements...never mind within a .join() function. Thank you, you opened a whole new route for me to explore.